# Period of a function. Help.

Tags: periodic-functions

How would we find the period of 
$$(-1)^{\operatorname{floor}(2x/\pi)}?$$
Please explain in a simple way.

---

I graphed it on Geogebra. The period turns out to be $\pi$. But I still don't quite unserstand the nature of the function.

Comment: Have you tried graphing it for some values?

Comment: Garry, I took the liberty of moving your comment (a response to Bill Wallis' suggestion) **to the post**. The passers-by may not see it in the comments, and may vote to close the question simply because they were left with the impression that you hadn't worked on this yourself at all. In other words, a pre-emptive strike :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that the function, depending on the exponent, is 1 or -1. So you are looking for a number T (the period) for which the function $-1^a=-1^{(a +T)}$. In particular for even values of the exponent you get 1, for odd values of the exponent you get -1. Moreover, $\mathrm{floor}(t)$ is continuous in ${R/Z}$. So when $2x/\pi=n$, $n$ belonging to $Z$? The answer is $x=n(\pi/2)$. So for odd values of $n$, like $\pi/2, 3\pi/2...$ you get a -1. For even values you get a 1. So the period of the function is $2((n+1)(\pi/2)- n(\pi/2))=\pi$. For any doubts, just ask.
And sorry for the bad format of the answer...it's my first one!

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference will help you. Just try putting dollar signs around random things and experiment is my advice. Great answer BTW!

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the advice by the way!

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^{\lfloor2x/\pi\rfloor}$

So, $2x/\pi$ will be floored to $0$, then 1 when it passes $\pi/2$, then $2$ when it passes $\pi$, then $3$ at $3\pi/2$, then... etc.
And when we take (-1) to this alternating sequence of odds and evens, we'll get -1's and 1's, respectively.

But the period at least is $\pi$.

Comment: According to your answer, I think the period should be π.

Comment: Yes it is! I'm so sorry, I mixed it up, that it must be a complete up and down for a period, not just the moment of change.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that, for $k$ integer, we have:

$$2k\pi<x<\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \quad \Rightarrow \quad 4k< \frac{2x}{\pi}<1+4k $$
so the floor is an even number. And

$$\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi<x<\pi+2k\pi \quad \Rightarrow \quad 1+4k< \frac{2x}{\pi}<2+4k $$
so the floor becomes odd.